# Display a view with many to many relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Having problem to display a generic list with books and its authors at view state.
A book can have one, two or three authors.

How shall I display a list that contains many books with right authors in view level?

// Fullmetalboy

The following tables of the database is:

Bok (eng. Book)

- BokID
- Titel
- Styckpris
- Sammanfattning

Bok_Forfattare (eng. Book_Author)

- Bok_ForfattareID
- BokID
- ForfattareID

Forfattare (eng. Author)

- ForfattareID
- Fornamn
- Efternamn

> ```
> <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"
>
>     Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<BokButik1.ViewModels.SokningPerformSearchViewModel>"
> ```
>
> %>
>
> ```
> <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent"
> ```
>
> runat="server">
>         PerformSearch
>
> ```
> <h2>Sökresultat</h2>
>
>
> <table>
> <% foreach (var bok in Model.Boks) { %> 
>
>
> <tr>
>     <td><%: bok.Titel %> av <%: bok.Bok_Forfattare %></td>
>     <td rowspan="2"><%: bok.Kategori.KategoriNamn %></td>
>     <td rowspan="2"><div id="Div1"><input type="submit"
> ```
>
> value="+ Add to cart" />
>       
>       
>           <%: bok.Sammanfattning %>
>       
>           
>           ..
>
> ```
> <% } %> 
> </table>
> ```

---

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult PerformSearch(string txtSearch, Kategori kategoriNummer)
{

    Search test = new Search(txtSearch, kategoriNummer);

    var asdf = test.HamtaBokListaFranSokFunktion();

    var results = new SokningPerformSearchViewModel
    {
        Boks = asdf,
        Bok_Forfattares = myIBok_ForfattareRepository.HamtaAllaBok_ForfattareNummer()
    };


    return View(results);   
}
```

---

```
namespace BokButik1.ViewModels
{
    public class SokningPerformSearchViewModel
    {
        public List<Bok> Boks { get; set; }

        public List<Bok_Forfattare> Bok_Forfattares { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would split your ViewModel into two ViewModels:

```
public class SokningPerformSearchViewModel
{
   public IList<BookSearchResultViewModel> Boks { get; set; }
}

public class BookSearchResultViewModel
{
   public IList<Bok> Boks { get; set; }

   public IList<Bok_Forfattare> Bok_Forfattares { get; set; }
}
```

For every book returned in the search results, create a new BookSearchResultViewModel and assign the book to Boks. Then fetch the authors and attach them to Bok_Forfattares. Next, add that book into your SokningPerformSearchViewModel.Boks list. Finally, return the SokningPerformSearchViewModel to your View.